# Naming subfunctions of a piecewise function

Tags: notation, soft-question

How do I name the subfunctions of a piecewise function? Is it like this?

\begin{align*}f(x) &\;=\; \begin{cases}f_{1}(x) = x - 1 & \text{if } x \leqslant 1 \\ f_{2}(x) = x^{2} & \text{if } x > 1\end{cases}\end{align*}

Comment: You don't have to define new function like $f_1$ and $f_2$. Sometimes though a new defintion is practical.

Comment: What I mean is that I am like "cross-referencing" the subfunctions, like for example, I'll insert a third subfunction for $f$, which is $f_{3}(x) = e^{-x} + f_{1}(x)$. Assume that $f_{1}$ is a very long expression. Instead of copying the entire expression ($f_{1}$), I'll just use $f_{1}(x)$.

Comment: Yes that's valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty subjective question. The answer is more about style than anything. I'd do something like:

> Let $f$ be defined by
> \begin{align*}f(x) &\;=\; \begin{cases}f_{1}(x) & \text{if } x \leqslant 1 \\ f_{2}(x) & \text{if } x > 1\end{cases}\end{align*}
> where $f_1(x) = x-1$ and $f_2(x) = x^2$.

But it's clear what you mean from how you've expressed it too.

Comment: So as long as it can be understood easily, it can be declared as a valid notation?

Comment: @soupless I depends on the purpose of your writing. I weigh clarity of writing highly. That doesn't make your notation "valid" necessarily.